# sklearn simpleimputer does not fill missing categorical NaN values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nan, categorical-data

I am using `SimpleImputer` from `sklearn.impute` to take care of my categorical NaN values. This is my training dataset prior to the processing:

```
msno.bar(train_df.sample(1000), labels=True, fontsize=8)
```

[image]

And here is what I'm doing. I'm basically dropping all columns that don't have at least 80% of its data and then applying the simple imputer for the missing categorical NaN values:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

limitPer = len(train_df) * .80
train_df = train_df.dropna(thresh=limitPer, axis=1)

nan_columns = train_df.loc[:, train_df.isnull().any()]
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")

for col, tp in train_df.dtypes.items():
    if tp == object or tp.name == "category":
        train_df[col] = imputer.fit_transform(train_df[[col]])
        
msno.bar(train_df, labels=True, fontsize=8)
```

The bar graph shows that, while the <80% columns have been dropped, the ones that remain failed to be inflated with dummy data:
[image]

Comment: Do those columns have categorical/string values? If not then since you're only imputing categorical/string columns they won't be imputed.

Comment: I agree with @AaronKeesing. I see nothing wrong in your code, so if the columns are not imputed, it must be because `tp` is not object or `tp.name` is not 'categorical'.